# find the sum of even number not exceed four million

Tags: java

```
class fibo {

    //int firstNumber = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        //int firstNumber = 0;
        int length = 4000000;
        int[] series = new int[length]; 
        //long[] sum = new long[4000000];
        long sum =0;
        series[0] = 0;
        series[1] = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i<4000000; i++){
            //firstNumber  = firstNumber + i;
            //System.out.println("fibo" + i);
            series[i] = series[i-1] + series[i-2];


            if(series[i] %2 == 0) {
                sum = sum + series[i];

            }

        }

        for(int j=0;j<length; j++){
            System.out.println("fibo Series" + series[j]);
        }               

    }

}
```

I got the answer, but the approach was different. What's wrong with this code?. Can anyone give an insight on this.

**The same code works when the length is 10.** I am not getting any expection on this, but the answer seems to be different. Its something -92719184589087346 which is incorrect.

Comment: What's the goal of this program?

Comment: Are you facing memory overflow problem ?

Comment: It sounds like the project Euler problem where you are summing the Fibonacci number less than four million.

Comment: BTW: You don't need to store every value and you can assume every third value is even.

Answer (score 4):

> What's wrong with this code?

Well it's taking the sum of the even numbers within the first four million Fibonacci numbers, *not* the even numbers within the sequence of Fibonacci numbers less than four million.

It's *also* creating an array of all the Fibonacci numbers it's seen, for no reason: you only ever need the last two at a time, so you can do that in constant space.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are trying to get the sum where the sum is less than 4million? because that isn't what you are calculating. You are calculating the sum at the 4 millionth index which is completely different.

The reason your answer is wrong (besides your logic being wrong) is that a long can't fit the number you are calculating. The 4 millionth entry in the fibonacci sequence is some number so incredibly large that it is overflowing your long. The overflow will make it wrap back into the negatives (probably multiple times).